# SCNNode at camera position

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, scnnode

I am trying to make my node start at the same position that I tap in a game but I can't figure it out

here is my code for where to position the node. I get my location from the tap gesture recognizer by:

```
let myLocation = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
```

Then I get the x and y position into a float value:

```
    let myx = Float(myLocation.x * 0.01)
    let myy = Float(myLocation.y * 0.01)
```

Then I set the nodes position(the camera is set at 30)

```
shapeNode.position = SCNVector3(x:myx, y:myy, z: 30.0)
```

The position is off by a lot and I can't figure out why...

Someone please help

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert location from 2D on screen into 3D in real world using `hittest()` to place object in real world